# How to make an exact clone of my debian system to distribute to Google Coral

Tags: debian, cloning

Background:

I have set up properly Mendel 10.0 (debian) in a Google Coral dev board, and installed my desired libraries (some through apt install, some through `git cloning` and `make install`). The [Google Coral Documentation](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/#flash-the-board) explains the procedure of flashing the `.img` system into a micro-SD card. After putting the hardware pins in the proper position and turning it on, it boots and installs the system. Then, changing the pins and booting the board, you can connect to it. No problem at all with that.

All the libraries installation process require Internet connection and some, a long time to compile and install. I wanted to make a clone of my system (which is less than 4gb, as I saw that it could be an issue if it was more than that) as a `.img` so I can clone and distribute the system with the exact libraries and programs, and configurations, to other Google Coral dev boards in a faster way, rather than having to run an `install.sh` in every board after installing the basic OS. **This sounds doable as the hardware is always the same (the same board always), and even the username or system name can be the same, so it shouldn't have any pathing nor naming problems.**

My research and testing so far:

I have already tried without success with the defunct Remastersys and it's newer [Linux Respin](https://gitlab.com/remastersys/LinuxRespin). I have seen some alternatives like [Systemback](https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Disk-Image-from-a-Linux-System-Using-Systemback), but this requires GUI, and it is not advised to connect a monitor and have a graphical insight in the GCoral dev board. I am not sure if [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/), or [dd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56406/how-to-distribute-my-debian-system), [more dd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41399/system-image-of-running-debian-system) can serve this purpose, as it looks quite complex to a non-expert user. Same for [squashfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260796/how-to-make-an-iso-of-my-installed-system), [Linux Live Kit (third option)](https://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/make-your-very-own-customized-linux-distro-from-your-current-installation) seems to create an `.iso`, and [changes to config files seem necessary](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-your-own-live-linux-cd-or-usb-distribution/).

**Is there a simple way to create a complete image of a debian system, to be able distribute it to other boards, just via command line?** I would flash that image with [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) into a MicroSD, and have the same system installed in different boards (which would be the same model).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to clone a Debian system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541512/fastest-way-to-clone-a-debian-system)

Comment: No! I did not mention it in the question, but they mention Clonezilla as well as gparted and the use of [parted through terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386420/how-to-open-gparted-terminal), which has a lot of their functionalities by it removed. The second (not accepted) answer might give details. Using [systemrescue](https://www.system-rescue.org/) also seems like an option, but again, not a simple and direct way like Remastersys was. @EsmaeelE